# Span of a set in Vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove that $$[v1, v2] = [v1-v2, v1+v2]$$ if $v1$, $v2$ belong to $V$(vector space). [ ] represent span of a set.

How can I solve this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important facts about spans are:

1. $[S]$ is closed under linear combinations
2. The statement $[S] \subseteq [T]$ is equivalent to the statement $S \subseteq [T]$.

We use the last property first. In particular, observe that the following are equivalent:

$[v_1,v_2] = [v_1-v_2,v_1+v_2]$

$[v_1,v_2] \subseteq [v_1-v_2,v_1+v_2] \wedge [v_1-v_2,v_1+v_2] \subseteq [v_1,v_2]$

$\{v_1,v_2\} \subseteq [v_1-v_2,v_1+v_2] \wedge \{v_1-v_2,v_1+v_2\} \subseteq [v_1,v_2]$

$v_1 \in [v_1-v_2,v_1+v_2] \wedge v_2 \in [v_1-v_2,v_1+v_2] \wedge v_1-v_2 \in [v_1,v_2] \wedge v_1+v_2 \in [v_1,v_2]$

The middle step uses fact 2.

What remains for you to do is to use fact 1. to prove these four statements. I'll do the first one for you. Observe that $$v_1 = \frac{1}{2}((v_1-v_2)+(v_1+v_2)).$$ Since $[v_1-v_2,v_1+v_2]$ is closed under linear combinations, this proves that $v_1 \in [v_1-v_2,v_1+v_2]$.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true if your field has characteristic 2

Comment: I agree. But I think the OP is working over the real numbers.